# ClickHouse spring jpa hibernate support

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, clickhouse

I am using Spring JPA with hibernate ORM project and want to integrate with ClickHouse. 
I found some references of ClickHouse JDBC which is working

ClickHouseJDBCDemo [ClickHouseJDBCDemo](https://github.com/kgrech/clickhouse-java/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/kgrech/clickhousespring/demo/ClickHouseJDBCDemo.java)

but was keen to know if there any better way to interact with database from Spring JPA like any ORM tool like Hibernate .

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Clickhouse is not relational DB, so there is no way to get full support using JPA and ORM frameworks

Comment: Mongodb and Neo4J not relational too, but both of them have full JPA support. JPA is about persistence interfaces, not about specific implementation.